# Posting status to Faceebok page using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am trying to post a status to a FB page using a Faceebok PHP SDK v4, but it doesn't work as I expected.

It posts to a page in name of page owner, but I want to post a status as a page itself. I have every possible permission on my access token.

How to do that? Is there any parameter that I need to send to tell Facebook, that I want to post on page's behalf, not page's owner behalf?

```
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($sAppId, $sAppSecret);

    $session = new FacebookSession($sToken);


    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/' . $pageId . '/feed', array(
        'message' => 'This is a test message',
    ));

    $response = $request->execute();
```

Comment: Get a page access token. You can read about the different access token types at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. Didn't know that pages have access tokens too